# stackoverflow exception when using android studio inspect code

Tags: android, lint

I am new here. When I use Inspect Code in Android Studio 0.9.2, I get the error:

```
null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.RelativeOverlapDetector$LayoutNode.canGrowLeft(RelativeOverlapDetector.java:265)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.RelativeOverlapDetector$LayoutNode.canGrowLeft(RelativeOverlapDetector.java:266)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.RelativeOverlapDetector$LayoutNode.canGrowLeft(RelativeOverlapDetector.java:266)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.RelativeOverlapDetector$LayoutNode.canGrowLeft(RelativeOverlapDetector.java:266)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.RelativeOverlapDetector$LayoutNode.canGrowLeft(RelativeOverlapDetector.java:266)
```

But when I run lint command in Term, it works fine.

Comment: If it's Android Studio error, then it should go to Android Studio bug tracker.

Comment: Try to add this code lintOptions {
      abortOnError true
  } in build.gradle.

Comment: ***User tried to answer question but received a Stack Overflow error***

Comment: Gradle DSL method not found: 'lintOptions()'  @HareshChhelana

Comment: @Mighter Yes I reported that, thanks for your comment